# How to successfully generate thrift processing of datanode in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: deployment, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I deployed Apache IoTDB standalone v1.3.0 instances on two ubuntu20 systems. One of them can be executed normally, and the other one also can connect normally after the deployment is completed, but the error log file of the dataNode keeps reporting an error: `2024-01-22 10:29:33,781 [pool-30-IoTDB-ClientRPC-Processor-35] ERROR o.a.t.s.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:258 - Thrift Error occurred during processing of message.`  Want to know why this error happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is usually caused by abnormal client connection in Apache IoTDB. The error message stated that if any client process exits abnormally without closing the connection, this error message will be printed. You can check from your error message on which jdbc or session connection it stated, and try to restart and reconnect it.